# Finding a cells positions (row, column) in nested tables

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have the following simple bit of jQuery which tells me what row/column a cell is inside of a table (excluding colspans).

```
var col = $this.index() + 1;
var row = $this.closest('tr').index() + 1;
```

Simple enough...except, my tables are nested inside other tables, and I don't know what the offset should be.  For example, I have cell (1,1), this cell is in a table, which is in the second cell of another table... And that first cell has a table with three columns.  So my cell is really (4,1)

EDIT: A more complete sample, with more test cases.  I've nearly got it solved.  Just some strange cases that are causing issues. (Now with coloured tests)

http://jsfiddle.net/gibble/J3uER/

...I realize this isn't normal, and the html is stupid, but it's what I need to work with.

Comment: What is the function, which executes this code: "var col = $this.index() + 1; var row = $this.closest('tr').index() + 1;" ?

Comment: Is the assumption that the inner table(s) match the structure of the parent table?  What if there is a 5x5 table in one cell, and a 2x2 table in another cell?  This does not lend itself to Cartesian coordinates.

Comment: @Webars, it doesn't much matter, but `$this` refers to a jQuery object of the current cell.

Comment: @Jeff B, yes, the column structure will work out correctly in that regard.

Comment: Does the text of each cell is unique?

Comment: @Webars, how does that matter?

Comment: Because you have a non standard situation, so we need some a non standard solution.

Comment: Unfortunately, with your new requirements, this becomes a difficult problem.  For instance, in the first "half row", you cannot know the coordinates of a cell without looking forward in the table to see how many cells are missing in the current row.  It might be more helpful if you tell us the broad problem you are trying to solve.  There might be a better way.

Comment: So close http://jsfiddle.net/gibble/J3uER/, this is the last thing I need to get done to finish this portion of a project!

Comment: Ultimately, this problem breaks down to this.  I have a series of nested html tables that get opened in excel (excel can open html tables nicely).  Some cells have a title attribute.  We want that title attribute to be a comment.  Unfortunately, the only way to add a comment, through html is non-trivial as well, and requires me knowing the row and col location of the cell (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276019/create-comment-in-excel-from-html-source)  So, I'm looking at each td with a title attribute, and building the appropriate markup.  It works, I just don't have the positioning right

Comment: Got all of the rows looking good.  Now I just need to get the columns right. http://jsfiddle.net/gibble/J3uER/17

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/juSm2/

I did it with iteration counters. It is a little bit complex, but your task too. :)
And some html modifications are necessary: we have to mark main rows to differ them from nested rows. I added the class .row to reach this.

```
$('td').click(function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(this).addClass('clicked');

    var row = 0;
    $('tr.row').each(function () {
        row++;
        if ( $(this).find('.clicked').length )
        {
            var td = 0;
            $(this).find('td').each(function () {
                if ( !$(this).find('td').length )
                {
                    td++;
                    if ( $(this).is('.clicked') )
                    {
                        alert( 'row = ' + row + ', td = ' + td );
                        $('.row .clicked').removeClass();
                    }
                }
            }); // td each
        }
    }); // .row each
}); // td click

<table>
    <tr class="row">
        <td>A1</td>
        <td>B1</td>
        ...
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
        <td>A2</td>
        <td>B2</td>
        ...
    </tr>
</table>
<table>
    <tr class="row">
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>A3</td>
                    <td>B3</td>
                    ...
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>F3</td>
                    <td>G3</td>
                    ...
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Webars, not bad, unfortunately I found a nuance in my html that makes this tougher....I may have not been accurate when I replied to  @Jeff B saying the tables would "work out to be a proper grid.  It appears to have holes.  Like this http://jsfiddle.net/bp6ur/1/ I really don't know how I'm going to figure this out...since I can't mess with the html.  And I added some rows to the inner tables, that doesn't work right either

Comment: Try to sort the information for every nested table to have only 1 row.

Comment: I can't change the data. This is how close I've got this. http://jsfiddle.net/bp6ur/13 (with colour coded tests)

Comment: Got it working in my test, just not quite in my real world project yet...damn. http://jsfiddle.net/gibble/J3uER/26